# Calculating HMM observation probability

Tags: math, probability, hidden-markov-models

I'm putting this one in [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) rather than [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange,com), seeing as I'm trying a programming approach rather than a math approach.

I have 3 matrices, a transition `trans`, an emission `emiss` (or observation error) and a state `state`.

To go with this, I also have a series of observations `obs`

My approach is rather simple:

```
prob = 1                       # Probability of sequence is 1 to start with
for o in obs:                  # For each observation:
    p_mult = dot(emiss, state) # Get the probability of each observation,
    p_mult = p_mult.get_elem(o)# select the corresponding observation
    prob = prob * p_mult       # and multiply that with the total probability
    state = dot(trans, state)  # Last, change the state using the transition matrix
print(prob)                    # Print answer
```

Where `dot(x,y)` is the dot product of two matrices (eg `{1x4}*{4x3}->{1x3}`) and `x.get_elem(y)` takes the `y`th element of the vector `x` .

For some reason this does not seem to work, as the probabilities I'm calculating is not matching that of others. Can someone give me a hint of what is wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: You are trying to implement a forward-backward algorithm.
You could test your approach by comparing step by step with the Wikipedia example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward%E2%80%93backward_algorithm#Example
There is also a proposed implementation in Python.